# What tests should be run in preparation for making contributions to Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I am preparing for making a minor bug fix to bazel java code. Am working on a Linux distribution.

Following the instructions in https://bazel.build/contributing.html but I encounter problems with two of the test instructions:

1. In the section about "Compiling bazel" the third parapgraph state: "In addition to the Bazel binary, you might want to build the various tools Bazel uses. They are located in //src/java_tools/..., //src/objc_tools/... and //src/tools/... and their directories contain README files describing their respective utility." If I follow this the //src/tools/... fail because there is no xcrun command in the Linux environment I am using. I suppose this is MacOS platform specific tests?
2. The next paragraph instructs you to build a distribution package, that you then unpack in a new directory, and then do: "bazel test //src/... //third_party/ijar/...".  I now get an error that windows.h is missing, which I suppose is Windows platform specific tests.

Some questions:

- So is there an easy way to run tests only for the current platform?
- Is the instructions good enough?
- If the instructions should be updated, what is the best way to notify the ones managing that documentation page?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest in contributing to Bazel! The [bazel-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bazel-dev) mailing list is a better avenue for these questions.

The tests that you want to run largely depend on the changes you make, but when you make a pull request, the Bazel CI will run all of Bazel's tests to make sure that nothing breaks.

> So is there an easy way to run tests only for the current platform?

It depends, and this is still a work in progress where we want to make Bazel more aware of platforms and toolchains without specifying additional flags.

In general, you don't need to modify or worry about the //src/*_tools packages unless you're making direct changes to them.

> Is the instructions good enough?

The instructions will never be perfect, and we're always looking for ways to make it clearer and more concise.

> If the instructions should be updated, what is the best way to notify the ones managing that documentation page?

Please [file an issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues) on the GitHub repository or email the bazel-dev mailing list for further discussion.